# chunking list prints "generator object chunks at 0x05DAF8D0" instead of the list

Tags: python, list, chunks

I used this code before and it was fine but somehow it now prints "[generator object chunks at 0x05DAF8D0]"  instead of printing the list in chunks. I don't know what I have touched to make the code fail.

```
 fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana']

 def chunks(l, n):
     for i in range(0, len(l), n):
         yield l[i:i+n]

 list_of_lists = [(chunks(fruit, 2))]

 print(list_of_lists)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print()` call is printing out the generator. But you want to see what the generator generates. And the generator is the first element of another list. Do this to see what is in it.

```
print (list(list_of_lists[0]))
```

But be aware that iterating through the generator uses it up. So don't expect the contents still to be there after the `print()` call.

Comment: I am just using it for a one time thing at the moment I have a big app in mind but I'm too dreadful at coding to actually make it and it uses Youtube API and all sorts of nonsense.